# Rapidminer decision tree using cross validation

Tags: rapidminer

I am using ten fold cross validation operator. I am using rapidminer first time so having some confusion that will I get 10 decision trees as a result. I have read that accuracy is average of all results so what is final output. Average of all?

Answer (score 0):

The aim of cross validation is to output a prediction about the performance a model will produce when presented with unseen data.

For the 10 fold case, the data is split into 10 partitions. There are 10 possible ways to get 9/10 of the data to make training sets and these are used to build 10 models. These models are applied to the remaining 1 partition to produce a performance estimate. The 10 performances are averaged. The end result is an average that is a reasonable estimate of the performance of a model on unseen data.

The remaining question is what is the model? The best answer is to use a model built on all the data and to assume it is close enough to the 10 models used to generate the average estimate.